# Error when i run a shortcut using it's path in cmd

Tags: cmd

I have a problem whenever I try to run some paths,
for example :

```
C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Menu\program.lnk
```

I had this error:

`not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file`.

As you can see this not a problem of space in the path,  how can I solve this?

Comment: i gave this path as an example and i forgot to mention that when i make a copy of a link and place it in another directotry i face this problem   , and i am sure that the .lnk is not the problem

Comment: What output from `dir C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Menu\program.lnk`?

Answer (score 0):

Having Tested This in the command prompt myself I found that on my windows 7 machine the command prompt doesn't like me appending the '.lnk' file extension on the end yet it seems to work to when I remove it. Other than I am not too sure. Could be a problem with the shortcut or the executable but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

i just had to add `cmd /C` as prefix of the command